# Goldberg-Rao maximum flow algorithm - why some arcs are never admissible?

Tags: algorithm, graph, max-flow, network-flow

I'm trying to implement Goldberg-Rao maxflow algorithm described in "[Beyond the Flow Decomposition Barrier](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.186.309&rep=rep1&type=pdf), 1988".
 The paper says that we are searching for the flow on admissible arcs.

```
The arc(vw) is admissible if distance(v) > distance(w) + length(vw).
```

To find arc's length we need the following computations:

```
Initially, F = sum of capacities of all arc's leaving the source
lambda = min (num of nodes ^ 2/3 , num of arcs ^ 1/2)
Δ = F/lambda
length equals 0 on arcs with large residual capacities (res.cap >= 3Δ) and 1 otherwise
```

During the algorithm computations F can only be decreased. So, if there are arcs with large capacities, they will never become admissible and we won't be able to push flow through them.
In [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4tel.png) F = 5, lambda = 1.7, Δ = 3 - so the arc from 2 to T with capacity of 10 is never admissible.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? And how exactly the limiting of arc's upper bound capacities improves the maxflow searching?

Comment: relevance to programming? Maybe you are looking for https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I haven't really looked into this in a while, but if you can't find an admissible arc don't you relabel the node and increase the distance?

Comment: @chris, as I get it, the problem is in length function, not distance. In example above distance difference between 2'nd and last node equals 1 - it's ok for admissibility conditions, but length is 0 because residual capacity 10 > 3Δ - this makes arc not admissible, therefore we wont push a flow through it, residual capacity will stay the same, and as soon as Δ can't become larger as it is, this arc won't be admissible..